# html form inside PHP loop incorrect post data

Tags: php, forms, loops, post, twig

Hi I have simple for each loop which creates buttons and inputs with value.
Problems appears when I'm trying to post data, i always post the first value from input field but values from buttons are fine. Take a look on code:

```
{% for user in users %}

  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="titles" action="
  {{site.uri.public}}/groups/user" method="post">
    //it's posting alway first value from loop
    <input type="text" name="delete1" value="{{ user.email}}">
    //it's working well
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="{{ user.email }}">
    </form>
    {% endfor %}
```

code for posting data:

```
     $post = $this->_app->request->post();
     $button = $post['delete']; //value of clicked button 
     $input= $post['delete1']; //value of first user
```

Can you give me a hint why input it's not working correctly?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide examples of both output you expect and output you receive?

Comment: for example value on button is k@gmail.com, same inside input, but when i receive output i get k@gmail.com from button and first user email for example c@gmail.com(k@gmail.com might be third one in array). I hope it's understandable.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not very familiar with `twig`, but I am going to guess that `{% for g in user.getGroupIds() %}` creates a reference `g` to the current object.  However, I do not see you use `g`.  You are using `user` instead.  Can you try using `value="{{ g.email }}"`?

Comment: I edit post it shouldn't confuse now with g. Can you take a look on it @RaphaelRafatpanah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I needed to use different ids of forms to differentiate them and some js function

```
{% set myVal = 1 %} 
{% for user in users %}
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="{{ myVal }}"
   name="{{ myVal }}" action="{{site.uri.public}}/groups/user" method="post">

   <input type="text" name="delete1" value="{{ user.email}}">
   <button type="submit" name="delete" value="{{ user.email }}" 
    onclick="setForm({{ myVal }})"  ></button>

    {% set myVal = myVal + 1 %}

    </form>
```